# Json Get Request using retrofit won't work

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

Until this api i had this ones and my code worked now i can not figure out what i need to get and what to put in Map also i don't know where to start to get this response into my app.

This api i know how work and i have working code for it :
https://gyazo.com/f2eb4858c48c31c5c48765a9e7512179

But this one api is really hard to figure for me.
https://gyazo.com/d2bad9dbe66bf7c51b169b54a68a003a

I really don't know what i need to put here in Map and how to get "result" array(if that is array list?? )

Thank you guys this is my unworking example.

Datas.class

```
package Model.BittrexApiModel;

public class Datas {

    private Result result;

    public Result getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(Result result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public Datas withDatas(Result result){
        this.result=result;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Here is my Result POJO CLASS

```
package Model.BittrexApiModel;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Result {

    @SerializedName("MarketName")
    @Expose
    private String marketName;
    @SerializedName("High")
    @Expose
    private Double high;
    @SerializedName("Low")
    @Expose
    private Double low;
    @SerializedName("Volume")
    @Expose
    private Double volume;
    @SerializedName("Last")
    @Expose
    private Double last;
    @SerializedName("BaseVolume")
    @Expose
    private Double baseVolume;
    @SerializedName("TimeStamp")
    @Expose
    private String timeStamp;
    @SerializedName("Bid")
    @Expose
    private Double bid;
    @SerializedName("Ask")
    @Expose
    private Double ask;
    @SerializedName("OpenBuyOrders")
    @Expose
    private Integer openBuyOrders;
    @SerializedName("OpenSellOrders")
    @Expose
    private Integer openSellOrders;
    @SerializedName("PrevDay")
    @Expose
    private Double prevDay;
    @SerializedName("Created")
    @Expose
    private String created;

    public String getMarketName() {
        return marketName;
    }

    public void setMarketName(String marketName) {
        this.marketName = marketName;
    }

    public Result withMarketName(String marketName) {
        this.marketName = marketName;
        return this;
    }

    public Double getHigh() {
        return high;
    }

    public void setHigh(Double high) {
        this.high = high;
    }

    public Result withHigh(Double high) {
        this.high = high;
        return this;
    }

    public Double getLow() {
        return low;
    }

    public void setLow(Double low) {
        this.low = low;
    }

    public Result withLow(Double low) {
        this.low = low;
        return this;
    }

    public Double getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(Double volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public Result withVolume(Double volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
        return this;
    }

    public Double getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(Double last) {
        this.last = last;
    }

    public Result withLast(Double last) {
        this.last = last;
        return this;
    }

    public Double getBaseVolume() {
        return baseVolume;
    }

    public void setBaseVolume(Double baseVolume) {
        this.baseVolume = baseVolume;
    }

    public Result withBaseVolume(Double baseVolume) {
        this.baseVolume = baseVolume;
        return this;
    }

    public String getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(String timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public Result withTimeStamp(String timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        return this;
    }

    public Double getBid() {
        return bid;
    }

    public void setBid(Double bid) {
        this.bid = bid;
    }

    public Result withBid(Double bid) {
        this.bid = bid;
        return this;
    }

    public Double getAsk() {
        return ask;
    }

    public void setAsk(Double ask) {
        this.ask = ask;
    }

    public Result withAsk(Double ask) {
        this.ask = ask;
        return this;
    }

    public Integer getOpenBuyOrders() {
        return openBuyOrders;
    }

    public void setOpenBuyOrders(Integer openBuyOrders) {
        this.openBuyOrders = openBuyOrders;
    }

    public Result withOpenBuyOrders(Integer openBuyOrders) {
        this.openBuyOrders = openBuyOrders;
        return this;
    }

    public Integer getOpenSellOrders() {
        return openSellOrders;
    }

    public void setOpenSellOrders(Integer openSellOrders) {
        this.openSellOrders = openSellOrders;
    }

    public Result withOpenSellOrders(Integer openSellOrders) {
        this.openSellOrders = openSellOrders;
        return this;
    }

    public Double getPrevDay() {
        return prevDay;
    }

    public void setPrevDay(Double prevDay) {
        this.prevDay = prevDay;
    }

    public Result withPrevDay(Double prevDay) {
        this.prevDay = prevDay;
        return this;
    }

    public String getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(String created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public Result withCreated(String created) {
        this.created = created;
        return this;
    }

}
```

And here is my BittrexResponse.class ( i think this one is not working.)

```java
package Model.BittrexApiModel;

import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class BittrexResponse {

    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private Boolean success;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private Map<String, Result> datas;


    public Map<String,Result> getDatas(){
        return datas;
    }

    public void setDatas(Map<String,Result> datas){
        this.datas=datas;
    }

    //private List<Result> result = new ArrayList<>();

    //This is first original JSONSCHEMA2POJO - SAVING RESPONSE DON't WORK
   // private List<Result> result = new ArrayList<Result>();

    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public BittrexResponse withSuccess(Boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
        return this;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public BittrexResponse withMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
        return this;
    }
```

ApiClient.class (working , tested on earlier examples)

```
package Model.CoinMarketCapApiModel;

import com.test.retrofit.CryptoCyber.Settings;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = Settings.getBase_url();
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();



            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(client)
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

I hope someone will help me to figure out why i don't know get data and save it to map...

P.s. here is link for api 
[CLICK HERE](https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries)

Comment: `result` shouldn't be a `Map<String, Result>` (which is mapped to a JSON Object), but rather a `List<Result>` (which is mapped to a JSON Array). Then, assuming that `Result` is well defined, the response should be correctly deserialized

Comment: can you please write me example how to map list to json array?

Comment: It should be done automatically by GSON if you change the type of `result` as described above

Comment: I did it how you said and still don't works ..Result class is the same as written above could you please recheck code to see if there is some problems with classes , 

   @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private List<Result> result = new ArrayList<Result>();

this is getter and setter
  public List<Result> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

Can you please check what i do wrong now ?

Comment: Did you have the chance to check if my answer helped you with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible way to design your classes to correctly parse the response.

### ApiResponse

```
public class ApiResponse {
    private boolean success;

    private String message;

    @SerializedName("result")
    private List<Market> markets;

    // Other fields + getters&setters
    ...
}
```

### Market

```
public class Market {

    @SerializedName("MarketName")
    private String marketName;

    @SerializedName("High")
    private double high;

    @SerializedName("Low")
    private double low;

    @SerializedName("Volume")
    private double volume;

    // Other fields + getters&setters
    ...
}
```

### Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Retrofit retrofit = createRetrofit();

        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
        retrofit2.Response<ApiResponse> response = api.getMarketSummaries().execute();
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            // Handle error case
        } else {
            ApiResponse marketApiResponse = response.body();
            System.out.println(marketApiResponse);
        }
    }

    private static Retrofit createRetrofit() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
}
```

It will print something like this (only first item of the list is reported for the sake of brevity):

```
ApiResponse{success=true, message='', markets=[Market{marketName='BTC-2GIVE', high=1.1E-6, low=9.7E-7, volume=3499023.70109898},
```